# How could I improve my sudoku-solving-programm in python? Getting "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, algorithm

I made a sudoku program that solves sudokus but the issue is that it is so inefficient that it keeps taking too many tries to solve it so it runs into this error:  `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. It only sometimes works on very easy sodokus. So the question is, How could I make it more efficient? I am new to the world of programming

```
listekords = []

bo = [[0,2,1,0,0,3,0,4,0]
     ,[0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0]
     ,[0,0,3,4,0,5,0,0,0]
     ,[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,8]
     ,[0,8,9,0,0,0,4,7,0]
     ,[0,6,0,8,7,0,2,0,0]
     ,[9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4]
     ,[2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
     ,[0,0,0,5,8,2,0,0,0]]

def printso():
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("----------------")

        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if j != 8:
                print(bo[i][j], end="")
            else:
                print(bo[i][j])

            if (j+1)% 3 == 0 and j != 8:
                print("|", end="")

def passt(number, ky, kx):
    if number in bo[ky]:
        return False
    else:
        for z in range(len(bo)):
            if bo[z][kx] == number:
                return False

        for x in range(len(bo)):
                ky1 = ky // 3
                kx1 = kx // 3
                c = x // 3

                if kx1 == 0:
                    for y in bo[x][0:3:1]:
                        if y == number and c == ky1:
                            return False

                if kx1 == 1:
                    for y in bo[x][3:6:1]:
                        if y == number and c == ky1:
                            return False

                if kx1 == 2:
                    for y in bo[x][6:9:1]:
                        if y == number and c == ky1:
                            return False

                if x == 8:
                    return True

def isempty(i, j):
    return bo[i][j] == 0

def back():
    [i, j] = listekords.pop(len(listekords)-1)
    b = bo[i][j]
    print(b)
    bo[i][j] = 0
    printso()
    return b+1

def forward(b, i, j):
    print("vor")
    bo[i][j] = b
    listekords.append([i, j])
    printso()
    return b

def solve(d, b):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if isempty(i, j):
                while not passt(b, i, j):
                    b += 1
                    print(b)

                if b > 9:
                    b = back()
                else:
                    forward(b, i, j)
                    b = 1
                print(d)
                solve(d+1, b)

solve(1, 1)
printso()
```

Comment: Can you provide *any* guidance as to how this works?

Comment: This might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: @InSync No, they don't take non-working code. Although, it could be a good place to post after fixing it, for advice on say, style and architecture. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/207529).

Comment: @wjandrea I thought they also accept code that requires optimization? OP said this works for simple cases.

Comment: it looks in solve for empty fields in the sudoku wich are representet by zeros. Then it tries to put evry number in this field. If a number between 0 - 9 fits it saves the koords of this fiels.Now if a number between 0 - 9 doesn't fit it removes the last koords from liste koords and tries a nother number between the old number and nine. I hope that helps:)

Comment: @InSync I just added a link to a guide in my last comment. It says: *"Code must already work as intended ... Code Review is not about fixing bugs"*. The semantics might be confusing though: OP's talking about improvements and efficiency, which is not wrong, but I would put it more strongly: I would talk about fixes and "blowing the stack".

Comment: This might or might not help: [What is the maximum recursion depth, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-and-how-to-increase-it)

Comment: This also might help: [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](/q/4929251/4518341) You can have a debugger launch when an exception occurs then examine the stack. Although, just reading the traceback is a good first step.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips.

Comment: What exactly are you recursing on? `d` never gets used except to be incremented on a recursive call. You shouldn't need more than 81 levels of recursion to solve a puzzle using the most naive algorithm (fill a square, recurse until the whole grid is filled, backtrack if it didn't work).

Comment: @chepner, d is the iteration counter. He's basically doing recursion instead of a loop, and isn't using recursion for the actual modification of the board (ie, his forward() function does not call itself, it is called by solve() each time)

Answer (score 0):

There is the one way to do with solve the `maximum recursion depth problem.`

```
import sys

sys.getrecursionlimit(1500)
```

By default, python has set the limit which is 1000.

Note: doing so is dangerous. But, the python is quite big so, some time it is okay to do this.

Answer (score -1):

So, answering "how can I make this more efficient" is a very open ended and general question.

Being a bit more specific though, the "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object." error is because of the way the solve function is written. By default, Python has a maximum recursion depth of 1000.

Changing the solve function to a loop like this will resolve the error.

```py
def solve(d, b):
    while True:
        might_be_solved = True
        for i in range(len(bo)):
            for j in range(len(bo[0])):
                if isempty(i, j):
                    might_be_solved = False
                    while not passt(b, i, j):
                        b += 1
                        print(b)

                    if b > 9:
                        b = back()
                    else:
                        forward(b, i, j)
                        b = 1
                    print(d)
                    d = d + 1
        if might_be_solved:
            break
```

Beyond that, the algorithm is basically doing a depth first search of every possible solution, starting with the top left cell and just proceeding in order. One optimization that would help a lot is if it scanned the sudoku and looked for the most constrained cell in order to decide which cell to set next.

Comment: Further increases in performance can be achieved by first attempting to identify cells which satisfy a number of solution characteristics such as (1) scan each row, column and square  to identify cells which can only contain a single value, (2) keep track of valid cell entries based on already identified single entry cells in the row, column, & square of the current cell.  (3) look for X-Y wing eliminations before going cell to cell trying valid entries.